# How to convert and use varchar data type as a datetime in mysql

Tags: mysql

Hello all,
               This is the format of my my-sql data type "rdate".
    Apr  1 2011 01:13:00:000PM

I want to use the order by rdate and i can't make it right order as the data type of rdate is varchar, So i want to convert it to date time , But no success.
I am trying to use date_format(str_to_date(`rdate`, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y%m');

Thanks
Mypixel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing:

```
ORDER BY str_to_date(rdate,'%M %d %Y %h:%i:%s')
```

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

Your Date is in the Following format:

```
%M  Month name (January..December)
%d  Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
%Y  Year, numeric, four digits
...
```

You have to tell `str_to_date` the format that your string is in. This means the way the specific parts of the date are displayed, spaces, etc.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/916c1/4)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

In your str_to_date function call, you need to specify what the format IS, not what you want it to be.  Try this:

```
str_to_date(rdate, '%M %d %Y %h:%i:%s'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table SET rdate=str_to_date(rdate,'%M %d %Y %h:%i:%s')
```

Just convert your column for good to datetime.